# Convex subsets in abstract groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Consider a group $G$. A *norm* on $G$ is a function $\|\cdot\|\colon G\to\mathbb R_+$ with (*) $\|gh\|\le\|g\|+\|h\|$ and $\|g\|=\|g^{-1}\|$ and $\|1\|=0$; the space of norms is a convex in $\mathbb R_+^G$.

I will call a subset $K$ (symmetric, containing $1$) of $G$ *convex* if the restriction of the space of norms to $\mathbb R_+^K$ is defined by the same conditions (*) when $g,h,gh$ all belong to $K$. For example, $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ is convex in $\mathbb Z$, but $\{-3,-1,0,1,3\}$ is not, because "$\|3\|\le3\|1\|$" does not follow from triangle inequalities in $K$ -- it requires "going through $2$".

What can be said about convex subsets? Has this already been considered? I am particularly interested in $G$ being a free group. I believe then that balls in a basis are convex. I would very much like a property such as: "if $K$ is convex and $g\in K$, then $K\cup g B$ is also convex", for $B$ a ball contained in $K$.

Comment: Please, provide a more rigorous definition of convexity: Do you mean "the set of restrictions of  norms on $G$?" And what does it mean "defined by the same conditions (*) restricted to "? On the face if it, this makes no sense since $K$ is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: It would be indeed be better define a norm on a (symmetric with 1) subset $K$ of a group to be a function satisfying the given conditions (i.e., the first two conditions and $\|gh\|\le\|g\|+\|h\|$ whenever $g,h,gh\in K$)

Comment: Maybe convexity in a Cayley-graph is what you need?

Comment: If notions of convexity for groups interest you in general, a couple years ago I studied translation-invariant abstract convex geometries with the property that arithmetic progressions $g, gh, ..., gh^k$ cannot have gaps (which I call midpointedness). For free groups I found the so-called "tree-convex sets", see https://villesalo.com/article/CC.pdf . YCor shows in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348388/convex-sets-on-the-discrete-heisenberg-group that the Heisenberg group has such a convex geometry too (just apply the exponential map to the usual convex sets).

Comment: (I think tree convex sets are very different from what you have, except on $\mathbb{Z}$. They also do not have your property in the last paragraph.)

Comment: @Echo Yes, convexity in a Cayley graph is what's on my mind; but it's more complicated: every $K$ is convex in the Cayley graph generated by $K$.

Comment: @Echo the given condition is independent of the choice of a Cayley graph

Comment: A few examples. In $\mathbf{Z}^2$ with basis $(e,f)$, the subsets $\{0,\pm e,\pm f\}$, $\{0,\pm e,\pm f,\pm (e+f)\}$, $\{0,\pm e,\pm f,e\pm f,-e\pm f\}$ are convex. In $A=\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z}$, the subset $A\smallsetminus\{3\}$ is convex but the subset $A\smallsetminus\{2,4\}$ is not convex.

Comment: In $G=F_{\{a,b,c,d,e\}}$ a free group, let $K$ contain $ab,b^{-1}cd,d^{-1}e,ace$ and all their subwords and inverses. Then $K$ is clearly geometrically convex in the Cayley graph of $G$, but the condition $\|ace\|\le\|ab\|+\|b^{-1}cd\|+\|d^{-1}e\|$ does not follow from triangle inequalities, since neither $acd$ nor $b^{-1}ce$ belong to $K$.